# Cant retrieve the content with simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<div class="divHeaderContainer1">
<table width="488" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="63">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="61">
<a href="jobs/jobdetails.php?recordID=5300"> Job Vacancy For Media and Production      Officer At The International Committee of the Red Cross (ICRC)&nbsp; </a>
<div class="jobDate">posted on 2013-05-10&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;by Admin |&nbsp;0  comments&nbsp;|&nbsp; 379 views </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

i tried to retrieve the href attribute from the a website(www.employmentng.com) with code below but it didnt return anything.

```
$url='http://www.employmentng.com/index.php?pageNum_Jobs=1&totalRows_Jobs=5127';
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('div[class=divHeaderContainer1]') as $container){
    foreach($html->find('table td[height]') as $table){
        foreach($table->find('a') as $link{
            echo $link-href;
        }

    }
}
```

I need help on this please

Comment: Any chance you mean `$container->find("table ...")` instead of `$html->find("table ...")`?

Comment: i meant $container->find('table...)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error there. And probably error reporting is off, so

Change line

```
foreach($table->find('a') as $link{
```

to line

```
foreach($table->find('a') as $link) {
```

EDIT:

one more error out there:

```
echo $link-href;
echo $link->href;
```